# Implementing ads in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ads

I'm looking to implement ads into my Windows Phone 8 app. I've implemented AdDuplex into it, and it's working perfectly.

I was looking into the Microsoft Advertisement SDK, but as far as i understood - that's only for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

Link: http://adsinapps.microsoft.com/

So my question is: where is the Windows Phone "version", what network would I use there ( Whats best), and the programming question - is it hard/easy to implement compared to AdDuplex?

AdDuplex was VERY easy:

```
            <adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" 
                AppId="81151" Margin="0,527,0,0" 
                />
```

Thanks for answers!
Erik

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8729

Comment: Ya, but how do I implement it?

Comment: Well now that you've got a link to it, you can read the documentation. If you've already read the documentation, what *specific* question do you have?

Comment: Well I suppose I can read it closer.. Thank you

Comment: If you're looking to use multiple ad providers I'd highly suggest checking out AdRotator: https://getadrotator.codeplex.com/